# Getting all system wallpapers

Tags: java, android, system, wallpaper

Is there a way to programatically get all the android system wallpapers?

I know how to get the current one, via `WallpaperManager`, and then save it to disk. But I want to know if there is a way to access all the pictures that act as system wallpaper included with the O.S.

Comment: You must clarify your question: "all the pictures that act as system wallpaper". As there can be only one system wallpaper active at a time, this might not be your question.
If your question is how to list all POSSIBLE wallpapers you must specify what makes a image a wallpaper, otherwise you can simply take a list of all images on the phone.

Comment: Android comes with a Wallpaper application by default. Its pictures to use as wallpapers are not files in the sd card. They are resources in the apk, instead. I want to access them by code. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the wallpapers are located in the launcher app. As the name of the launcher and its resources may vary accross devices, there is no way to create a reliable way to do this.

On stock Android the wallpapers are located in Launcher2.apk:res/drawable-*somedpi*. On my devices they were in the drawable-hdpi folder, but this may be different on others.

First get the resources of the launcher (com.android.Launcher2.apk) as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7205854/1005915) answer.

Then you can list the resources, using a method similar to the one in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495585/how-can-i-get-a-directory-listing-of-resources-from-my-android-app) question.

I haven't tried out all this myself, so it might not work as expected.

Comment: You can install wallpapers and remove then independent of the launcher. So inspecting the launchers package does not help!

Comment: If you decompile the Launcer2.apk with apktool, you will see it contains the wallpapers. I'm not totaly sure what you mean by 'installing a wallpaper'.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in a direction. I'm able to get a `Resources` for `com.android.launcher` (API level 7), but listing files in `res` dir returns nothing. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score -3):

Just figure out where they are saved and access them that way.

Comment: This could possibly pass as a comment, but it certainly isn't an answer. Sorry!