# button click to go to android wallpaper choose

Tags: android, button, click, wallpaper

I'm new in android programming. I want something to know:

I want users to click on a button to launch wallpaper chooser.

What should I do?

Comment: u mean to show gallery for choosing wallpaper?

Answer (score 1):

WallpaperManager is probably what you're looking for: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following code in you `button` `onClickListener()`

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
 = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
try {
 myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.id.imageName);  
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will change the wallpaper to `imageName`.

Comment: thanks, but my app is not a wallpaper app. i want to offer users to change their wallpaper by clicking on an button. i mean when the users click on a button they be led to wallpaers change.

Comment: where they will be lead to have a wallpaper change? gallery or some selected images?

Comment: did you mean that you already have a selected image and want to change the wallpaper when button is clicked?

Comment: I really grateful for you, but what i mean is I want to create a button in my activity and when users click on it lead them to wallpapers. somthing like a shortcut that lead users to wallpapers,

Comment: you want to open default stock wallpapers? see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10692374/1979347