# drawbacks of using metadata tag in Android manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

i just want to ask if there is any drawbacks of using metadata tags in the Android Manifest to store information such as server destination, API keys, etc.

any performance issue? (if there are many metadatas)
security issue?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manifest is public information, accessible to all installed apps (e.g. [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.susatthi.ManifestViewer&hl=en)).  I wouldn't store API keys there, because generally you don't want other (potentially malicious) apps from snooping such information.  There's not much you can do to prevent the user getting hold of such information, but you can at least try to make it hard for other developers.

It is also worth noting that a resource file can also be loaded by other apps (see [Getting resources of another Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205415/getting-resources-of-another-application)), so I wouldn't store that data there either.  Compile-time constants are much harder to get hold of, and are probably the ideal place to store anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

No any drawbacks . And it also not cause any performance issue.

Comment: but i think it's better way to store it in xml file (eg. config.xml) and put it in values folder

Comment: hmm.. may I ask why do you think its better?

Comment: information defined into manifest has public access to all installed app. That's why...