# Retrieve the bold strings in a text

Tags: android

I am stuck in a small problem. I have text retrieved from the permission window.

Now I found out a way to retrieve the app name . This is how I did it:

```
private String Namer(String parse){
        if(parse.length() > 30) {
            parse = parse.substring(parse.indexOf("********") + 6, parse.length());
            parse = parse.substring(0, parse.indexOf("*******"));
            return parse;
        } else {
            return parse;
        }
}
```

and this is how i use it:

```
List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> NodeInfo;
    AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();
    for (Map.Entry<OriginalPermissions, String> permissions : 

detect.entrySet()) {
       NodeInfo = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText(permissions.getValue());


    Log.d("Information", Namer(Namer(String.valueOf(NodeInfo))));
}
```

But the problem is that the permission window text can be different. Is there any way in which I could just retrieve the bold text from the permission window?

Thanks

Comment: `String` can't contain the bold or another way styled text. It stores only raw characters.

Comment: Is there any way in which I can get the above app name even if the text in the permission window is in other languages?

Comment: first show how you get that text currently

Comment: I posted the code above. I am retrieving the string between "allow" and "to".

Comment: ok, but I'm asking to show the magic of how you get the text, that you pass to the `appNamer(String parse)` method

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: try using `NodeInfo.getText()`. It returns a `CharSequence`, which may contain the styled text in spans

Comment: But in different languages, I will not have the strings "Allow" and "to", So how could i retrieve the app name in those cases

Comment: as I said, `getText()` probably contains the spans of styled text. So you will be able to get the bold text from it.

Comment: It is mot taking the getText() method

Comment: then show what is your `NodeInfo` at least. Which type is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156466/discussion-between-thomas-and-vlad-matvienko).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you see ([source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/PackageInstaller/+/android-7.0.0_r7/src/com/android/packageinstaller/permission/ui/GrantPermissionsActivity.java#233)), title of `GrantPermissionsActivity` is a `Spanned` text. Instead relying on the surrounding text you can get the value of first span (with bold text) using such method:

```
public String getFirstSpanValueFromTitle(Spanned text) {
    StyleSpan[] spans = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), StyleSpan.class);
    if (spans.length > 0) {
        int start = text.getSpanStart(spans[0]);
        int end = text.getSpanEnd(spans[0]);
        return String.valueOf(text.subSequence(start, end));
    }
    return "";
}
```

Otherwise, you will need to get the value of the `permission_warning_template` resource string for each language and hardcode it in you code.

**UPDATE**:

Example how to get title text from AccessibilityEvent object:

```
String pkgName = event.getPackageName().toString();
if ("com.google.android.packageinstaller".equals(pkgName)) {
    AccessibilityNodeInfo root = event.getSource();
    List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> nodes = 
            root.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_message");
    if (nodes.size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "First span value: " + getFirstSpanValueFromTitle((Spanned) nodes.get(0).getText()));
    }
}
```

Comment: SpannedText value for this method you can get from AccessibilityNodeInfo object that contais text "Allow Camera to user device storage." using AccessibilityNodeInfo.getText() method. It returns CharSequence type and you should cast it to SpannedText.

Comment: How it is not strange, but it is possible and very simple to realise. BTW I did not know about this possibility before you ask it and found a solution in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205415/getting-resources-of-another-application.

Comment: In this thread, I saw that it is possible if both the apps are written by me. For example, can I retrieve the string resource named "permission_warning_template" for each language dynamically from the android aource code?

Comment: Yes, you can. This is working code:
    Resources r = getActivity().getPackageManager()
       
 .getResourcesForApplication("com.google.android.packageinstaller");
    int id = r.getIdentifier("com.android.packageinstaller:string/permission_warning_template", null, null);
    Log.e(TAG,"Value: " + r.getString(id));

Comment: The code is correct and should work fine. Are you sure this method is being called?

Comment: I am able to retrieve strings from com.android.settings. but why not from com.android.packageinstaller?

Comment: You can read resources of any installed apps in device. I tested it before post here. Please check may be error in another place of your code.