# How to play mp4 in the raw of another application?

Tags: android, mp4, android-videoview

My app package name is `com.example.app.a`, I try to play the mp4 resource from application b `com.example.app.b` like this:

```
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.picker);
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.app.b/raw/keyboard_anim_theme"));
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

but the `Can't play this video` dialog shows. How can I play the mp4 in another application. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting resources of another Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205415/getting-resources-of-another-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with `getIdentifier` ?

check below code and check.

```
int rawId = getResources().getIdentifier("keyboard_anim_theme",  "raw", "com.example.app.b");
String path = "android.resource://com.example.app.b/" + rawId;
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```