# How can I create Android Application plugins/extensions that can be installed as an APK or from market?

Tags: android

I'm actually investigating the possibility to have an application that fulfill the following requirements:

- The Main Application may have 5 deactivated functionalities
- If you try to use a deactivated functionality, the application invites you to download an extension that can be installed as an APK or from market.
- Once the functionality is installed, it becomes activated and then it can be used.

So we can have some free/not free functionalities. I've already seen such a behavior in some applications but I don't remember the name.

Is there something in the Android SDK to be used? how it can be implemented?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In product apps is what you are looking for, I believe.

Comment: I don't get what you mean...

Comment: If we helped you it is good idea to mark correct answer ;-)

Comment: Of course! once my problem is solved. I'll mark the correct answer, don't worry.

Comment: Anas EL HAJJAJI how did you solve your problem? I want to create an app that has 5 parts to activate when user buy them. But I want those parts separate from main app and when user buy them then added to main app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you looking for, but let me suggest something to get you started (*probably*)

For the sake of example, say, in your application, for instance, you have 2 buttons (instead of 5)

BUTTON 1 and BUTTON 2.

When you start your application, check if the necessary applications (third party to your own application) are installed or not using the [`PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)

This is a pseudo code that I use in my app to check if Google Maps is installed or not on the users device:

```
boolean installedMaps = false;

// CHECK IF AN APPLICATION IS INSTALLED
PackageManager pkManager = getPackageManager();
try {
    PackageInfo pkInfo = pkManager.getPackageInfo("com.google.android.apps.maps", 0); // REPLACE THIS "com.google.android.apps.maps" WITH THE ACTUAL PACAKAGE NAME
    // Log.e("pkInfo", pkInfo.toString());
    installedMaps = true;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    installedMaps = false;
}
```

If the `boolean installedMaps` returns **true**, enable the button. Otherwise, prompt the user to with a Dialog to download the application off Google Play.

And do this for each function you need to Activate or Deactivate.

NOTE: You will need to know the Package Name of the other application for that. If you do not know it, it can be found by running the application on your device and checking the logcat.

If you also need to share Content between all concerned application, you might also consider making use of [`Content Providers`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Again, I am not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for. Please do correct if I am wrong in my assumption.

Comment: I thinks that's the solution. Thanks! How can the different installed APKs share resources to avoid duplicated resources?

Comment: @AnasELHAJJAJI: Put them all into the "core", and then expose that content between all concerned applications with a Content Provider.

Answer (score 7):

You can create apks with Service and use http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html to connect to this service. And this service can do what you want so only your imagination is your limit ;-)

I recommend read about this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid it is possible to share more data between 2 and more apps. But they should be singned with same key.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) The service can call an activity? so have a User Interface once its APK installed?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Read about Intents, BroadcastReceivers and Service (local and those which are using AIDL) and this should help you. Custom permissions may be useful too.

Comment: It might interests you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062946/how-can-i-use-the-paid-version-of-my-app-as-a-key-to-the-free-version

Answer (score 3):

You have to build 6 different apps/apks and submit them to Play Store. And there are at least 2 options to integrate apps together:

1. If your functionality takes full screen than you can just launch appropriate activities from plugin apps.
2. If main screen (the one from main app) should include code (functionality), resources from plugin apps (layouts, images, etc) than look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid. Using that configuration you can access code from plugin app with reflection by class name.

You can also access resources from another apk using Resources res = mPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication("org.example.foo");
refer to [Is it possible to access resources in another APK without using content providers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593046/is-it-possible-to-access-resources-in-another-apk-without-using-content-provider) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. The main app can be installed but not the extensions?

Comment: what do you mean? All apps should be published to Play Store. If required plugin is not installed - just forward user to Play Store by appropriate link. You can detect if the app is installed.

Comment: Although the accepted answer will work it doesn't do what question asked for. This answer is much closer to answering the question but would help if you add example of how to access code from other apps as you have done for resources.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - what exactly you mean by "additional functionalities". Problem is quite complex.

1. Check for application existanece - just use `PackageManager` and try to find desired package if found use it if not ask user for installation.
2. Resources access (images, layouts etc.) - also with `PackageManager`
3. Use some portions of code - many different ways to get the effect. Intents (startActivityForResult()), Content providers.

Probably better approach to introduce free/paid features is just use in-app payment.