# Android Modular Programming

Tags: android, modular

My Problem might not be valid. And the points I mention here might be little incorrect as I am neither perfect nor expert.

I have a shopping application and I want to start building a modular application. Like I want to add Affiliate User( the module which adds certain functionality or this will display some extra pages in an application) in the application.

A similar situation happens in the Frameworks: We add and enable the certain module and in return framework load everything as required.

for this, I want following changes like:

1. add an entry in the NavigationView displaying "Affiliate Label".
2. load fragments (just adding one more fragment for one more label/option from navigation view).

Let's say I have a library project that contains a Fragment and all relevant code.

How can I build the application automatically let's say just by writing "true" somewhere in the XML?

Automatically here means label is added, Intents are performed on click of label etc.

```
<Modules>
<enable>true/false</enable>
</Modules>
```

This is just the simple scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this (like everywhere when it comes to writing code) in many possible ways.

1. The "file" way: 
   Make a new file named something like modules.txt with key value pairs. Load the file and check whether a module is enabled or not.
2. The "Constant" way:
   Make an abstract class which only contains public static final variables which describe your modules.
3. The "package manager" way:
   See [create Android Application plugins/extensions (apk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644539/how-can-i-create-android-application-plugins-extensions-that-can-be-installed-as)
4. The "multiple" apk way:
   Note that this is not reccomended!

> we encourage you to develop and publish a single APK

[multiple apk support](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)

Answer (score 1):

To add to codewing's answer, you can also use Gradle's resource management capabilities to accomplish this, so you only ever need to look in one place for an enabled/disabled status.

For this, you have 2 solid options.

The first starts with a boolean which can be split by flavor:

```
<bool name="module_x_enabled">true</bool>
```

The second would be to inject your values into a String resource after Gradle merges the resources by adding something like this to your build.gradle file, then comparing that enabled value:

```
<string name="module_x_enabled">MODULE_X_ENABLED_PLACEHOLDER</string>


android.applicationVariants.all{ variant ->
    variant.mergeResources.doLast{    
        replaceInValues(variant, 'MODULE_X_ENABLED_PLACEHOLDER', MODULE_X_ENABLED)
    }
}

def replaceInValues(variant, fromString, toString) {
    File valuesFile = file("${buildDir}/intermediates/res/merged/${variant.dirName}/values/values.xml")
    String content = valuesFile.getText('UTF-8')
    content = content.replaceAll(fromString, toString)
    valuesFile.write(content, 'UTF-8')
}
```

Where `MODULE_X_ENABLED` would be a setting in your `gradle.properties` file like:

```
MODULE_X_ENABLED=true
```

Edit: or better yet,

Why not pull the settings from some kind of server so that you don't need to rebuild and relaunch to update a client's module?

Comment: Sorry @Guardanis, I didn't understood much about the process related to changing strings only and gradle. As i am a new to android technology. I will try to get more relevant information  so that i can understand what is the content all about.

Comment: Please guide the things should i refer to like (understanding gradle process etc) or please explain a bit more.

Comment: Are you using Gradle/Android Studio or was your question for another build system?

Comment: yes my question was for Gradle/Android Studio. but i didn't understand how changing strings makes everything works.

Comment: It allows you to check your resources via Boolean.valueOf(context.getString(R.string.module_x_enabled)) and determine whether the module should be implemented within your app or disabled. Similar to codewing's #2 using constants, just using gradle to change your resources

Comment: I am sorry but the question was bit different. May be i confused a little bit (Sorry i said bit)...   

I want to learn the architecture/(Modular approach) so that whenever i add library module_x in the main project and enable it by your method or from codewing's method.  All the work is done automatically

Comment: think like app is like browser you add a addon it make an entry on the toolbar and make some actions. Similar way in application you add a library project we get a label on navigation view and corresponding action. This is just a simple scenario. What if many modules interact amny dynamic changes are to be done. What architecture should be envolved

Comment: I think I see what you're saying now. But the issue is: you still have to tell the system about your module no matter what it is. Even if you're using a List<ModuleInterface> or something like that, you still have to add your modules to that list in order for them to work (which is what codewing's and my answer is more about; determining whether it should add the module you've already implemented to that list or not). AFAIK there is no way to just add a library and have it automatically implement itself, even if similar modules are already implemented.